# How to implement SSO among 1st-party apps with OpenID Connect and ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, cookies, openid-connect

I have what seems to be an odd situation and I'm not entirely sure that I'm going about it the right way, but here goes ...

I have an OpenId Connect provider implemented using Identity Server.  This OIDC provider protects an API, multiple 1st-party apps and multiple third-party apps.  The 3rd-party apps are working fine.  It's the 1st-party apps that are giving me a hard time because I'm trying to do SSO among them all, i.e. if you log in/out of one then you're also logged in/out of the others.  This is different from the 3rd-party apps where you log in/out individually but they piggyback on your existing OIDC session.

What I have working is my 1st-party apps recognize the auth cookie from my OIDC provider because they are sharing the same data protection keys.  If I log into the OIDC provider directly then navigate to the 1st-party app, the app detects the cookie and indicates that I am already logged in.

What *isn't* working is that if I do login flow that I just described (log into the OIDC provider directly then navigate to the 1st-party app) it never actually goes through the entire OIDC flow so the resulting ClaimsIdentity is missing the access_token and refresh_token claim that OIDC usually injects after hitting the token endpoint.

So my question is: is there a better way to accomplish what I'm trying to do, or is there a way to force the client to complete the OIDC flow even if it already has the auth cookie?

**Startup.cs from 1st-party app**

```
var dataProtector = //Custom DataProtector

app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType("oidc");

app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
{
    AuthenticationType = "Cookies",
    CookieName = "AuthTicket",
    CookieDomain = Properties.Settings.Default.CookieDomain,
    CookiePath = "/",
    ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(20),
    LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
    LogoutPath = new PathString("/Account/Logout"),
    TicketDataFormat = new AspNetTicketDataFormat(new DataProtectorShim(dataProtector))
});

app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
{
    AuthenticationType = "oidc",
    ClientId = Properties.Settings.Default.ClientId,
    ClientSecret = Properties.Settings.Default.ClientSecret,
    Authority = Properties.Settings.Default.Authority,
    RedirectUri = $"{Properties.Settings.Default.BaseSiteUrl}/account/login",
    ResponseType = "code id_token",
    Scope = "openid profile api",
    TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        NameClaimType = "name",
        RoleClaimType = "role"
    },
    SignInAsAuthenticationType = "Cookies",
    Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
    { 
        AuthorizationCodeReceived = async n =>
        {
            var tokenClient = new TokenClient($"{Properties.Settings.Default.Authority}/connect/token",
                    Properties.Settings.Default.ClientId,
                    Properties.Settings.Default.ClientSecret);

            var tokenResponse = await tokenClient.RequestAuthorizationCodeAsync(n.Code, n.RedirectUri);

            if (tokenResponse.IsError)
            {
                throw new Exception(tokenResponse.Error);
            }

            // use the access token to retrieve claims from userinfo
            var userInfoClient = new UserInfoClient($"{Properties.Settings.Default.Authority}/connect/userinfo");

            var userInfoResponse = await userInfoClient.GetAsync(tokenResponse.AccessToken);

            // create new identity
            var id = new ClaimsIdentity(n.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.AuthenticationType);
            id.AddClaims(userInfoResponse.Claims);

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(tokenResponse.AccessToken))
            {
                id.AddClaim(new Claim("access_token", tokenResponse.AccessToken));
                id.AddClaim(new Claim("expires_at", DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(tokenResponse.ExpiresIn).ToLocalTime().ToString()));
            }

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(tokenResponse.RefreshToken))
            {
                id.AddClaim(new Claim("refresh_token", tokenResponse.RefreshToken));
            }

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(n.ProtocolMessage.IdToken))
            {
                id.AddClaim(new Claim("id_token", n.ProtocolMessage.IdToken));
            }

            if (n.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.Claims.Any(c => c.Type == "sid"))
            {
                id.AddClaim(new Claim("sid", n.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.FindFirst("sid").Value));
            }

            n.AuthenticationTicket = new AuthenticationTicket(new ClaimsIdentity(id.Claims, n.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.AuthenticationType, "name", "role"),
                n.AuthenticationTicket.Properties);
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I did not fully understood the scenario, but as far as I can see you want to alter the SSO behavior you get by identity provider.

Protocol provides you with the ability to control this. The authentication request can contain the`prompt` parameter to select the desired interaction behavior with your application.

> **prompt**
>
> OPTIONAL. Space delimited, case sensitive list of ASCII string values
>   that specifies whether the Authorization Server prompts the End-User
>   for reauthentication and consent.

There are four parameters you can choose (taken from [3.1.2.1. Authentication Request](http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#AuthRequest) section of specification without descriptions),

- none
- login
- consent
- select_account

As far as I can see, you can use the **prompt=login** to force a user login or **prompt=select_account** to alter user accounts between different users. Also you can combine this with **login_hint** parameter to fine tune the usage of this parameter

Furthermore, if you want to force SSO behavior on top pf prompt parameter, you can use **prompt=none**